# Does string constant pool works with singleton annotated variables too?

Tags: java, android, singleton

```
object Keys {
    @Singleton
    const val KEY_Q = "question"
    @Singleton
    const val KEY_ID = "quesid"
}
```

I am using Singleton annotation with many string variables in my singleton class. I wanted to ask as by default a string variable is stored in the constant string pool, and during the updating process, JVM checks in the string pool if the same variable is available or not, if yes then it returns the reference of the same without creating a new one.

[image: as we can see in the picture]

Now I want to ask, does this process works the same when we are using **singleton annotation** with our string variables. If yes then is there any benefit for me to use such a class with these annotations with different variables. I am a newbie to singletons please describe in detail. Thanks

Comment: The annotation is irrelevant.  String literals always go in the pool.

Comment: will it take the same amount of memory? Actually, I want the same variable to be used every time, instead of creating a new reference of the same. Is it possible here?

Comment: 1) The amount of memory will also be irrelevant.  2)  You have 3 different variables, so obviously 3 variables will be used.  But is that what you mean?  Variables and values are different things.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the reply. I wanted to ask if KEY_Q is used multiple times in several activities then does JVM creates different references or the same variable is used every time resulting in lesser memory usage.

Comment: You are overthinking this.  The strings here occupy maybe 30 or 40 bytes each.  Your program in its entirety probably uses millions ... or even billions of bytes.  30 or 40 bytes "wasted" (on a singleton) will make absolutely no difference. Move on.  Think about a problem that actually matters ...

Comment: And besides, Dawood's comment is correct.  It makes no difference to the spring pool if you use the `@Singleton` annotation or not.  (But if you really, really want to know, `s1` and `s3` in your example will refer to the same object ... in the string pool.   There are a bazillion other Q&As about the string pool.  I suggest you do some searching and reading.)

Comment: sir, It actually matters to me. I have just shared a smaller code block. I would like to clarify my doubts regarding the same. If you can answer then it's fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235572/discussion-between-ramanjeet-and-stephen-c).

Answer (score 1):

Annotations make no difference to string pool behavior in Java.  If your example was Java, the `@Singleton` annotations would not save memory<sup>1</sup>.

There is a very simple rule that covers what goes into the string pool in Java.

- If a string is a result of evaluating a *compile time constant expression* then a single copy is placed in the string pool.  The JLS specifies what a compile time constant expression is<sup>2</sup>.
- The **only** other circumstance in which a string goes into the string pool<sup>3</sup> is if some code *explicitly* calls `intern` on it.

However ...

In a **modern** JVM on modern hardware, it is most likely to be *irrelevant* whether a string goes into the string pool.

- The string pool is part of the heap and is garbage collected like the rest of the heap.
- The space taken by each individual string literal is most likely to be trivial compared to the rest of your application's memory usage.  A few bytes, compared with megabytes ... or gigabytes.
- If you think you can `intern` strings and exploit the special property of strings in the string pool (by using `==` to compare strings) you are treading on very dangerous grounds.  This is a micro-optimization ... and it only works if you can be sure that you have interned all of the strings.  (And besides, interning is more expensive that a few string comparisons, so your attempt at optimizing might be a failure.)
- Finally, since Java 9, the GC performs automatic string de-duping for strings that have survived a few GC cycles.  So if you really do have a lot of string data with a lot of duplicates, the best solution is to let the GC handle it.

---

<sup>1 - I cannot tell you exactly what this means for your example, because you are using syntax that is not valid Java.  Java doesn't have a `const`, `val` or `object` keywords.  This *looks* like Kotlin.

2 - Common examples are a string *literal* or a concatenation of string *literals*, but there are others; see [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

3 - It is implementation dependent whether the string itself or a copy of the string goes into the pool.  But it is really difficult for an application to distinguish the different behaviors.</sup>

Comment: So, no benefits of using @Singleton Annotation with const string variables!

Comment: If you are doing it just to save memory, there is no benefit.   And even if there was a benefit, it would be trivial to the degree of being a complete waste of programmer time!